# sql query in foreach for gridview yii2

Tags: yii2

In gridview in first column I have a list of courier. I need to get count of orders for each courier. In sql it looks like

```
SELECT order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,
    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'sent' then 1 else 0 end) paid
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= '2016-12-01' AND
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date <= '2016-12-31' 
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method = eu_dpd;
```

What if I create array with couriers and do it sql query in foreach, like

```
`$courier = [eu_dpd,eu_dhl,eu_ups]
foreach ($courier  as $value) {
    SELECT order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method,
    sum(case `order`.order_status when 'sent' then 1 else 0 end) paid
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= '2016-12-01' AND
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date <= '2016-12-31' 
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method = $value;
}`
```

How do I apply it in yii2?

Comment: How about using `group by` instead of `AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method = $value;` and `foreach`?

Comment: @Yupik maybe its possible. Could you tell me how it get in gridview? Where there should be request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for complex query a simple way is  the createCommand  based on the normal db connection

```
$yourModel = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(
  "SELECT order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method as deliver_method,
      sum(case `order`.order_status when 'sent' then 1 else 0 end) paid
  FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
  WHERE order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= '2016-12-01' 
  AND order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date <= '2016-12-31' 
  AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method  = '" .$value . "';")->queryOne();
```

then you can refer to the result as

```
echo $yourModel['deliver_method'];
echo $yourModel['paid'];
```

for gridview you could use a sqlDataProvider and pass the dataProvider to your view http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider.html

Comment: If you need  inside foreach you can put the createCommand in foreach . .. depend by your application need ..

Comment: Your code put into actionIndex in controller, right?